# DOM Element Variable to get Nth result?

Tags: html, css, google-tag-manager

I am trying to set up a custom variable in GTM (Tag Manager) using the DOM Element with CSS Selector with the following CSS snippet: `dd.qds-c-post-detail__value`

The problem is there are 4 matches to this on the page, so the variable is defined as the first match. I need the 3rd match. There doesn't appear to be any portion of the CSS that is unique to the 3rd one. Is there a way I can get GTM to always find the 3rd result?

Answer (score 0):

Say for example all have the same button class - `qds-c-post-detail__value`

Create a Custom JS variable in Google Tag Manager that will fetch all the elements and selects (returns) the 3rd one.

```
function() {
  var sameButtonElements = document.querySelectorAll('.qds-c-post-detail__value');
  return sameButtonElements[2] #index starts from 0 & fetch the 3rd DOM element
}
```

Use this Custom JS variable to match with your requirements. You can also iterate to find out if the element was clicked or not using `{{Click Element}}` pre-defined variable.

Comment: This makes sense. I also got it to work by setting up a DOM variable [ div.qds-c-post-detail__value:nth-child(3)] Are there any reasons to use one method vs the other?